# netbeans - debugger exited with code 0xc0000135

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I need to install debugger in netbeans. I have already installed gdb in the mingw/bin directory with  `mingw-get.exe install gdb`. I have added the line `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`. However when i run the debugger it gives out this message:

`During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.`

Can anyone explain how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 8.0.2 returns “During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27463115/2985643).

Comment: @skomisa No its not the same probem. I dont thave any problem with libraries. It just gives out that error with code 0xc0000135.

Comment: OK. I just managed to to reproduce your problem using NetBeans 8.2. After acknowledging the _Debugger Error_ prompt and pressing the **Stop** button the output (debug) window is empty. Is that what happens for you as well?

Comment: @skomisa yes, the output window is empty.

Comment: There is a bug report for this issue for NetBeans 8.2, but it looks like NetBeans Support could not reproduce it. See NetBeans [Bug 258292 - Gdb fails as during startup program exited with code 0xc0000135](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258292).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that i have found the solution. I added the line `C:\MinGW\bin` to the "Path" environment variable (in the control panel) . Now the message error doesnt appear and the debugger is running.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the issue for me as well. Thanks.